# How do I format Format invoice_date like this: July 19, 2014 IN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
July 19, 2014 IN SQL
```

SELECT invoice_number, invoice_date, invoice_total
    F

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, i have. I tried to use CONVERT(VARCHAR

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Please share the table structure, sample input data, your attempts, and the expected output

Comment: Little bit explanation will help you ultimately. Because, without knowing details, it is so hard to answer and give you solution.

Comment: the original invoice_date is in this format 2014-06-16

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

You need [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
DATE_FORMAT(invoice_date, "%M %d, %Y")
```

or

```
DATE_FORMAT(invoice_date, "%M %e, %Y")
```

if you don't need leading `0` in day.